# I can't detect event touch in event.getX and event.getY

Tags: android, events, ontouchlistener

[image: Calender view]

I have a problem. I can't detect event touch in my calendar.
My calendar create by Gridview.
I want to touch my calendar to red line in the picture
(touch down 8 and move to 22) but I can detect event touch to blue line in the picture (touch down 3 and move to 5)
and I try to check action to red line is **ACTION_CANCLE**. I don't know why this happened.

**gridcell.xml**

```
     <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="5dp" >
 <LinearLayout   
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/laycal">
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txt_grid"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:textSize="16sp" >
        </TextView>
    </LinearLayout>
  </LinearLayout>
```

**layout_grid.xml**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >
    <GridView
         android:numColumns="7"
         android:layout_width="match_parent"
         android:layout_height="match_parent"
         android:id="@+id/gridcal"
         />
</LinearLayout>
```

**cal_adpter.java**

```
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        View grid;
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) mContext
            .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

        if (convertView == null) {
            grid = new View(mContext);
            grid = inflater.inflate(R.layout.gridcell, null);
            TextView textView = (TextView) grid.findViewById(R.id.txt_grid);
            textView.setText(cal[position]);

int x,y=0;
Linearlayout laycal =(Linearlayout)findViewById(R.id.laycal);
laycal.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        switch(event.getAction()){

        case(ACTION_DOWN);
        x = event.getX();
        y = event.getY();
        break;

        case(ACTION_MOVE);
        x = event.getX();
        y = event.getY();
        break;

        case(ACTION_UP);
        x = event.getX();
        y = event.getY();
        break;         
    }
    return true;
}});

            } else {
                grid = (View) convertView;
            }

            return grid;
        }
```

Comment: int x,y=0; <---- Here is your problem!

Comment: int x,y=0; is no problem but event not in case ACTION_DOWN ACTION_MOVE and ACTION_UP.It's event in case ACTION_CANCLE.